# How to swap images on click with unknown image name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two images which must swap by clicking on one of them:

```
<img id="large-img" src="" />
<img id="small-img" src="" />
```

Since people will upload images through content management system - the `img src` are unknown.

Here is [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7uUX7/)

Comment: So, start using **some** of the JavaScript for your task? We won't be writing the code for you!

Comment: You would know the image name to swap it in... can you expand more on how you're getting this image from the CMS and what language you're looking for help with

Comment: You have to have at lease some reference to the image. Otherwise is impossible.

Comment: Instead of posting more and more links, post actual HTML and JavaScript that represent the problem at hand.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I'm sorry - simply because of deadlines my head doesn't work right now. Sorry once again ( one vote from me )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/7uUX7/2/).

Basically, you swap their `src` attributes, it doesn't matter that you don't know their values. Check the jsfiddle, click on any image and *voilà!*. Magic

```
$('#myimage1,#myimage2').on('click', function() {
    var $img1 = $('#myimage1');
    var $img2 = $('#myimage2');
    var url = $img1.attr('src');
    $img1.attr('src', $img2.attr('src'));
    $img2.attr('src', url);
});
```

Comment: You're assigning a handler to all images, and are assuming there are only two in question.

Comment: @cookie monster there are only two in my case < thanks for clarification.

Comment: I'm working with what the OP gave us. I'm not going to think about all possible scenarios of which the question may be a simplification.

Comment: @OscarPaz: If there's not enough information to answer, then don't. But there was at least enough to know that your answer would very likely be wrong.

Comment: @Robert002 It doesn't really matter that there are only two in your case. You should write code that is robust, it's not that hard, look at the updated version

Comment: In the updated version you are creating the `$img1` and `$img2` objectrs every time, which may be as robust, but certainly slower.

Comment: @OscarPaz So your solution is to create globals? I can guarantee you this would only matter in a tight loop, which is not the case here. That is a safe assumption, and yes the code is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code on your jsfiddle, It's works nice,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#myimage1").click(function(){
    var imgsrc=$("#myimage2").attr('src');
    $("#myimage2").attr('src', $("#myimage1").attr('src'));
    $("#myimage1").attr('src',imgsrc);
});

$("#myimage2").click(function(){
    var imgsrc=$("#myimage1").attr('src');
    $("#myimage1").attr('src', $("#myimage2").attr('src'));
    $("#myimage2").attr('src',imgsrc);
});

});
```